# Trying to use ajax for form submit, but $_POST-array is empty

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send javascript arrays to a new page with ajax. There are lots of questions on that on SO, and after scouring the answers I decided to use Ajax like so:

```
var test = {}; 
test['a1'] = 1;  
test['a2'] = 2;

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#form').submit(function(e){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'newpage.php',
        data: {test:test},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        }
    });
    window.open('newpage.php', 'formres','width=800,height=800,resizeable,scrollbars');
    e.preventDefault();
});

});
```

It works in that the new window open as it should - but the $_POST-array is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I have tried {test:test}, {'test':test} and just test. I will try to serialize the data and see what happens. @Louis H: thank you, hadn't thought of that. I will try with Firebug. Thanks a bunch, all of you!

Edit2: It still bothers me though that the test array didn't go through. As Kevin B pointed out, the post request should hold the parameters a1 and a2, but it doesn't. I'll post again if I find out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you already tracked the http-requests body with the development tools of a modern browser? Could `test` be empty inside the submit event?

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but post should be all uppercase

Comment: If you replace `{test:test}` with `test` it should send a post request with 2 form parameters `a1` and `a2`

Comment: Can you try this: {'test':test} . Added quotes to the data's key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$(this).serialize()
```

for your data. this will serialize the form into correct post-data, which can be used by $_POST

more information: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

and maybe you want to display the result of this post in the popup? then you should open the window in the callback function.

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'newpage.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            window.open('newpage.php', 'formres','width=800,height=800,resizeable,scrollbars');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: The problem though is that I am only using the form to pass variables containing arrays to the new page - serialize() doesn't seem to work for that.

Comment: One Question: Why do you think your post array is empty? Have you analyzed the request (using firebug for example) or is this just the (wrong) code your are using in your first post?
There you are calling the "newpage.php" directly after firing the async. http-request, that can't work.

Comment: No, I changed my code to open the popup in the callback, much better idea. And you are right, Firebug has the correct values in the POST-array - but I must be doing something stupid, because they don't make their way to the new page. I have tried all suggestions, my ajax function now has async :false, the popup in the callback function and return false - no luck. Thanks all the same - at least learned a thing or two about ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmz, please try to add

```
'async': false,
```

This is used to wait for the POST to be send before opening the new window.

Answer (score 0):

Two years later and I find this still relevant. Content headers have to be set for `POST`, and in Javascript, you do it like this:

```
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```